# which time series class to use in R for financial data?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

for working with financial time series, like daily stock prices or intraday data, which time series packages are preferred? xts, plain zoo, or timeSeries or something else?
I use both xts and zoo, but sometimes not sure to use xts exclusively or sometimes zoo have advantage of lighter overhead; also, I remembered a review paper on all these packages by Rmetrics, which claims that xts cannot even finish some tests they did. But I cannot find the paper now.

Comment: The rmetrics paper is on the rmetrics website.

Comment: Related: [Which R time/date class and package to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354974/which-r-time-date-class-and-package-to-use)

Answer (score 5):

I am rather happy with [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) and [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) and alternate between the two.

Nothing forces you to use one exclusively. As [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) is a little older, some packages interface it rather than [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts).  But [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) has extensions which provide extra functionality (e.g. the indexing) which make it a valid option.

Other folks may be perfectly happy with [Rmetrics](http://www.rmetrics.org) classes. It all depends, and is to some extent a matter of personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I myself use **zoo** as my 'default' option since I have the feeling this is the most common time series class used in the community.

I think both xts and zoo are good choices. SInce they are well known in the community.

There are even more time series classes available apart from
**xts** and **zoo**. See also [Task View Time Series](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).
But I myself try to stay away from too exotic time series classes except I need the particular features. This makes it easier for others to understand the code.