# Which R time/date class and package to use?

Tags: datetime, r, date, time-series

I have a limited time series exposure in R. So, I wonder which time/date class (and associated package) would be most appropriate to start with.

Among the plethora of packages available at [CRAN task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html), I so far favor the [`timeDate`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html), which is a S4 oriented and has nice support for location dependent particularities such as holidays and daylight saving times.

The community apparently favors the [`zoo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package. [`chron`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/index.html) is also popular.
[edit: Here is a list of time/date implementations which `lubridate` package refers to:  **POSIXct, POSIXlt, Date, chron, yearmon, yearqtr, zoo, zooreg, timeDate, xts, its, ti, jul, timeSeries,  fts**. Also `lubridate` itself has  handy time classes `duration`, `period` and `interval`.]

Would really appreciate if somebody with experience with multiple packages would share his opinion on how the available time/date classes compare in terms of usability and extensibility.

Some points of interest (in random order):

- internationalization (holidays, timezones etc)
- readily available statistical modeling procedures
- readily available visualization tools
- ease of use
- compatibility with builtin date/time-series classes (POSIX,ts)
- extensibility (S4 is desirable)
- best to use with [`lubridate`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/)

Thanks.

Comment: Just want to point out that the zoo package is a time series package. Its not itself a date/time package but rather works with date/time classes from R and other packages, e.g. POSIXct, chron, timeDate, etc.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. I've started looking in the documentation of zoo. It also has a brief comparison to other packages. Thanks for the package :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(I am moving this from the comments to the answer portion of stackoverflow at the request of the original poster.)

There is an article in [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) ("R Help Desk", p. 29) that specifically compares `Date`, `POSIXct` and `chron`. (The 1st two are in core of R and `chron` is a package.)

`timeDate` class (in the `timeDate` package) is based on `POSIXct` but has extra time zone/financial center support.

For regularly spaced series the the `tis` package supports many notions of dates.

The `mondate` package supports accounting dates.

The `zoo` time series package supports just about any date/time class and also has `yearmon` and `yearqtr` for `ts` compatibility.

The `xts` time series package works on top of `zoo` and handles the most common date/time classes by translating them to `POSIXct` and back again.

There is also information in the [Time Series CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Answer (score 14):

Use POSIXct and lubridate.

Comment: After several days of playing with different types I arrived to the same conclusion. Thanks for the package. Something what I am somewhat missing in the `lubridate` is the ability to round, floor and ceiling to fractions of units. Say floor all times to 5th and 35th minutes of an hour.

Comment: I see we've lost that functionality somewhere along the way - I've opened a bug report at https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/issue/81

Answer (score 5):

Rmetrics actually wrote a (free) ebook on the subject, "A Discussion of Time Series Objects for R in Finance", available at https://www.rmetrics.org/ebooks-tseries

Comment: Thanks Jean. Great book. It's about zoo, xts and timeSeries packages but have a couple of very useful chapters on handling date-time objects as well.

Comment: -1 This is a misleading and biased account when it comes to zoo/xts and is not recommended.  I suggest you read the 5 zoo vignettes, 1 xts vignette and the 2 reference manuals for accurate information.  For example, the ebook's 2nd question is supposed to explain the difference between zoo/xts and timeSeries but it nowhere mentions the key difference which is that zoo is general in its handling of any time/date index class that satisfies certain minimal properties  whereas timeSeries is hardcoded to use a particular one internally.

Answer (score 1):

Did you search old questions here?  This has been discussed *a lot* -- use a search term such as

```
 [r] zoo
```

to search for, say, `zoo` within the R tag.

Of course this has also been discussed to death on the r-sig-finance list and other places.

FWIW my money is on zoo and xts.  And to avoid S4 unless you *really really* need it.

Comment: My question is about comparison of time series packages not about specific [r] zoo, I expect somebody with experience with several of time/date packages to share his knowledge.

Comment: That's how you start searching for `zoo`, then you can search for `timeDate` etc. Makes sense?

Comment: I would better start reading zoo + timeDate + chron + xts + dozens or other packages documentation instead of
exposing myself to deprecatory teaching on how to search. If you are such a search expert, why just not to point me to the relevant discussion, instead of spending your time on these sort of comments? On r.sig.finance there is only one post mentioning zoo and timeDate together

Comment: Your strategy gives [this](http://r-project.markmail.org/search/?q=zoo+timeDate+). Hundreds of questions are asked every month about zoo package.

Comment: No it doesn't. I told you to search on Stackoverflow.

Comment: There is an article in R News 4/1 that specifically compares Date, POSIXct and chron. The 1st two are in core of R. timeDate class is based on POSIXct but has exta time zone/financial center support. For regular series the the tis package supports many notions of dates. The mondate package supports accounting dates. zoo supports just about any date class and the xts package works on top of zoo and handles the most common date/time classes by translating them to POSIXct and back again.

Comment: @VitoshKa The link you provided shows < 10 questions per month.  How did you arrive at 100 per month?

Comment: @G. Grothendieck could you please repost your comment as an answer, so we can vote it up. It directly addresses the question.

Comment: @Joshua, in the link I sent there are hits for zoo and timeDate together. If you look for zoo only, you will get 150 hits only for November. If we gonna nitpick, not all of them are questions but that hardly makes a difference to my point.

Comment: @VitoshKa No nitpicking intended; I simply did not understand and was curious.