# how, in R, to plot time of day versus calendar date

Tags: r, time, format, plot

I regret that I come to post here after being burned-out on hours of Internet searching regarding this simplistic question.

I have several data sets to plot in R, each consisting of two columns of data: time, date.  I am using R 2.11.0 on a Windows computer, via the Rgui.

Time is "time of day" that an event is observed. As an example, it is recognized as:

```
Factor w/ 87 levels "5:53","5:54",..: 84 85 85 85 86 ...
```

Date is calendar date, recognized as:

```
Class 'Date'  num [1:730] 13879 13880 13881 13882 13883 ...
```

The time values are recorded in the format of a 24-hr clock, h:mm or hh:mm.  The date values are displayed yyyy-mm-dd.

I want to plot time (y-axis) vs. date (x-axis).

Using

```
plot(date,time)
```

gives an accurate-looking plot, but the y-axis is labeled as the numeric factor values (about 0 to 90), rather than the desired, temporally-ordered levels of the factor variable.  The x-axis is labeled in the desired, human-readable format.

How can I correct this?  Is there a "time of day" format in R that I can convert my "time" variable into?  I will subsequently like to do arithmetic on the time values as well, and would not mind having to carry one column of values to use in plotting and one column of values for maths.

I ran across several examples online of manipulation of (date + time) variables in R, and converting those to different formats.  I do not believe this is my problem, as I have separate fields for time and date and want to plot one against the other.

My thanks to you in advance for your suggestions, or your directions to a web-accessible resource (no appropriate libraries or bookstores at my location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this, but you can always label the y-axis yourself.  Adjust the `ticksAt` vector below to find something that looks suitable for your data.

```
Data <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+1:10,time=paste(5,41:50,sep=":"))
with(Data, plot(date,time,yaxt="n"))
ticksAt <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
axis(2, at=ticksAt, labels=as.character(Data$time)[ticksAt])
```

`?plot.zoo` has some good examples of how to create pretty axis annotations, though some of them may be zoo-specific.  `?par` is also a good resource.

Comment: I had wondered if just doing "dummy labeling" on the y-axis would be the most direct means for me to reach my desired end.  I had hoped there was a way to plot the time values themselves ("5:53", "5:54", etc.), instead of the numeric counterparts from the factor (84, 85; as shown in the original question); in part, because different data sets will require individualized axis annotations. Thank you for your clear, direct example. For immediate work on this, I favor your form of solution.

Answer (score 0):

ts and timeSeries are two good choices.
Take a look at 
[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354974/which-r-time-date-class-and-package-to-use)

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I looked some at what I could find on ts (e.g., http://127.0.0.1:15268/library/stats/html/plot.ts.html, http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm). My impression is that that does not address my issue, which is basically how to have the y-axis labeled with times of day. (The data appear to plot correctly with plot(), with the x-axis labeled with calendar dates.) I still need to look into timeSeries, as well as the many packages at the "Related" posting. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two vectors, one of Date class named "dt" and the other a factor named "tm":

```
 x <- paste(as.character(dt[1:2]), as.character(tm))
 strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
## [1] "2008-01-01 05:53:00" "2008-01-02 05:54:00"
class(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
##  [1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXlt"
```

Comment: Having separate time and date variables is an integral part of the situation for this question, since the topic of interest is investigating how the times of day for different events varies over the course of calendar years. I am afraid that I do not grasp the value of combining these two into one object, despite the ability to convert them to POSIX.

Comment: Rather than do your own function creation for time objects, a class whose existence I am unaware, I thought you could use the TimeDateClass to do one of either create differences between a date time variable and a derived variable truncated to midnight or create and auxiliary variable which had all of its date portion reassigned to a common date. You would then be able to use the formatting features built in for your y-axis labeling.

Comment: I see. You are right, that could be useful for arithmetic with the time values. I neglected that benefit and was still stuck on a the point of getting a direct way of plotting values that would be recognized and arrayed as times of day, analogous to the ability to get date-only values recognized in R within a base installation. Thank you for the redirection.