# best time date format for R

Tags: datetime, r, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which R time/date class and package to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354974/which-r-time-date-class-and-package-to-use)

Hello,

I want to use a time date format for R, but there are so many packages that have their own format that I am a bit lost.

I was thinking of using the POSIXct/POSIXlt format. Is it the best (flexible enough for all use)

Thanks
fRed

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354974/which-r-time-date-class-and-package-to-use

Comment: @Marek, The SO question cited was about time series dates and times and is not necessarily the same as dates and times in general.  `zoo` separates the two but other time series packages hard code one or more date time classes or implicitly use their own notion of what the index should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date` and `POSIXct` are both *Base R* types and *highly recommended*.

Packages such as [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) or [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) use *these types* for indexing.  Other packages like [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lubridate) use them for date computation and parsing.

So your intuition was right: use `Date` and `POSIXct`.

Comment: Note that `zoo` can use those classes but generally speaking it can use just about any index class and does not favor those or any other class.

Comment: Similarly, lubridate works with every R date time class that I'm aware of

Comment: I believe its true that both lubridate and zoo work through an API but at another level its a bit different since lubridate is about dates and times whereas in zoo its about an index and the index can be a date or time but does not really even have to be what is conventionally regarded as one.  For example `zoo(1:26, letters)` is a valid zoo series on the alphabet.

Comment: @Dirk EddelBuettel: Can POSIX format in R be extended to support time periods of less than 1 second?

Comment: It already does!  Try `options('digits.sec'=7); Sys.time()`. Time for R is in _fractional_ seconds, but the _default display_ is rounded to whole seconds.

Answer (score 5):

The [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) Help Desk article is about how to choose the appropriate class.

Comment: You're getting some mileage out of that article today Gabor.